# how to create contact us form in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I made a contact us form and having problem that how a user submitted details will be delivered to my email.
I am newbie and do not understand this from [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email) 
 "the MAIL_URL environment variable should be of the form smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/     "
I want to deploy my meteor app on Meteor free server so please guide me how i should write the above URL thing in **serevr/smpt**
You can have look at my [source code](https://github.com/soni1/foody) **client/templates/contact_us/contact_us.html**
 and 
**contact_us.js** and **server/common.js** and can tell me if my rest of code is also correct to perform the contact us form functionality.

Comment: do you have an account on Mailgun?

Answer (score 1):

You should create an account on Mailgun (default by Meteor).

Let's say you use your gmail account which is waquar@gmail.com and your password is pass123:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://waquar:pass123@smtp.gmail.com:587/'
});
```

Both your server method and client code seem to be correct, try steps above and let us know if it works.

Comment: what password i should write here ? my gmail or Mailgun? my code is also on Github so it will expose my password to every one else . @KG32

Comment: To be honest I can't remember, in my project I set my Mailgun password to be exactly the same as gmail, but I guess it should be gmail password, you can test it. Right, you will expose it, that's why you should make the repository private if you expose sensitive data in your code, I guess there's no way around it.

Comment: Edit: you can set this environment variable outside your code, take a look at: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables . I'd suggest testing setting it in your code without pushing to github to see if it works as supposed and then trying to set it from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I have in my ~/.bashrc of my dev environment something like:

```
export MAIL_URL='smtp://myemail%40example.com:mypass@mysmtpserver.com:587/'
```

You can test with a server.js like:

```
Email.send({
  from: "meteor.email.2014@example.com",
  to: "your-personal-email-here@example.com",
  subject: "Meteor Can Send Emails",
  text: "Its pretty easy to send emails."
});
```

as described in https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-email for gmail. After receiving the test email, you can remove that file.

In production I use *mup* with the save *env* variable.